# Probability of a deck of cards of 8 blue and 5 white

Tags: probability

A deck of cards consists of 8 blue cards and 5 white cards. A simple random sample (random draws without replacement) of 6 cards is selected. What is the chance that one of the colors appears twice as many times as the other?

$$\Pr(\text{one card appearing Blue card})=\frac{8}{13}$$
$$\Pr(\text{second card appearing blue card})=\frac{7}{12}$$
$$\Pr(\text{One of the Color appear twice})=\frac{8}{13} \cdot \frac{7}{12}$$

Comment: This isn't a question about mathematica.

Comment: In _Mathematica_, this would be computed as `Probability[x == 2 y || y == 2 x, Distributed[{x, y}, MultivariateHypergeometricDistribution[6, {8, 5}]]]` with the answer of $\frac{70}{143}$, which agrees with the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want the probability of $4$ blue, $2$ white **or** $2$ blue, $4$ white.

Imagine the cards have distinct ID numbers. There are $\binom{13}{6}$ ways to choose $6$ cards from the $13$. These ways are all **equally likely**.

Now we want to count the "favourables," that is, the number of hands that have $4$ blue and $2$ white, or $2$ blue and $4$ white.

There are $\binom{8}{4}$ ways to choose $4$ blue. For each of these ways, there are $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to choose the accompanying whites, for a total of $\binom{8}{4}\binom{5}{2}$. Similarly, the number of ways to pick $2$ blue and $4$ white is $\binom{8}{2}\binom{5}{4}$. Add, to find the total number of favourables, and divide by $\binom{13}{6}$.

Comment: Thanks Andrea Nicolas its Clear!

Comment: You are welcome. The goal is to put you in a position where you can easily answer similar questions.